# Is "but" a conjunction or an adverb?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Quote from Narnia:

> It wasn’t nearly such a nice cave as Mr. Tumnus’s, Lucy thought—just a hole in the ground but dry and earthy.

ChatGPT said the "but" serves as an conjunction in here to contrast or contradict the preceding clause, indicating that the cave was not as nice as Mr. Tumnus's cave despite having some positive qualities.

But why couldn't this “but” function as an adverb meaning "only"？

Comment: I would say that it contradicts 'just a hole in the ground'. IIRC Tumnus's cave was an underground house. This one is just an empty cave, _but_ it is at least dry and has an earth floor.

Comment: It *could* function as a pronoun referring to "hole" but it doesn't; it's linking (and contrasting) things so it's a conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

When "but" functions as an adverb, it typically means "only this and no more". For example:

> I only regret that I have but one life to lose for my country.

Here "but one" means "only one and no more". In your sentence, it would mean "only dry and earthy and no more", yet that doesn't seem to make sense. Instead, "but" seems to contrast "just a hole in the ground" (negative) with "dry and earthy" (positive); that is what "but" typically does when it functions as a conjunction.